# Git best practice

Tags: git

Hi I'm new to Git and wondering how I should approach the following scenario.

I have a development branch which im working on new features, then I realise my live app has a bug. I fix the bug on master. I now want/need the bugfix on the development branch.

How should I deal with this? Do I go to the development branch and merge master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of many scenarios where `git` really shines.

All you have to do is pull `master` into  your development branch by checking out the feature branch and issuing a

```
git pull origin master
```

If the development branch conflicts with main because the bugfix changes the same lines as the development branch, you may prefer to rebase your branch on top of `master`.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

This re-applies your changes as if they were done *after* changes currently on `master` and can make for a cleaner merge in some cases.

You can safely experiment with both of these commands by branching off your development branch into a throw-away test branch, then using `git diff` to compare your throw-away branch with your development branch.